# how to get prototype div selector as object

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I'm a noob to prototype/jquery, and when I try to do this in the chrome console, on a page with a div called "contains_filter_select":

```
>> $("contains_filter_select" )
<div id=​"contains_filter_select">​…​</div>​
```

but it appears to somehow not be an object?

```
>> $("contains_filter_select").text("abc")
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'text'

 $("#contains_filter_select")
 null
```

I feel like I'm missing something trivial here, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: The `$()` function in your question looks like Prototype's, not jQuery's.

Comment: Yep it's prototype. My bad, updating text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> `>> $("contains_filter_select").text("abc")`
>
> `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'text'`

That suggests to me that you aren't using jQuery at all, but some other library. There are several libraries that use the `$` symbol: jQuery, Prototype, and MooTools (at least). The way both Prototype and MooTools work, when you use `$("contains_filter_select")`, you'll get back a reference to the actual `div` object; jQuery is different, with jQuery you get back a wrapper around a matching set of elements (and the string would be a CSS-style selector, with a `#` before the element ID, unlike Prototype and MooTools where it's just an ID value). With jQuery, you wouldn't get the error you're getting, even if your selector didn't work. With Prototype or MooTools, I'm pretty sure you would, as neither of them adds a `text` method to elements.

So the answer is: I don't think you're using jQuery on that page at all. Double-check the script tags. (FWIW, if you happen to be using the popular on-line tool [jsFiddle](http://jsdfiddle.net), it defaults to MooTools if you don't change the drop-downs on the left.)

Comment: That doesn't match the error. If he didn't have jQuery at all it would say "$ is not a function". It's the selector that's a problem.

Comment: @GregPettit: Did you bother to read what I wrote? Both Prototype and MooTools use `$` as well, and unlike jQuery, they return the actual element. Which doesn't have a `text` method. Which perfectly matches the error message given.

Comment: TJ, not sure why you're so angry and yet have a huge score for being helpful. ;-) It's all good my friend, all good! But let's make sure the selector is fixed first.

Comment: @GregPettit: I'm not angry. I do find it a bit frustrating when people say an answer is wrong when they seem not to have read it. Sorry if I came off a little strong. I agree with you that the OP is notable by his/her absence here... :-) My guess is they're using jsFiddle, which defaults to MooTools. (Actually, I should put that in the answer.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried multiple things to recreate that error, but I can't seem to do so... Hopefully properly prefixing the selectors along with actually using jQuery will solve the problem. +1 for a nicely worded and thought out answer!

Comment: @AndrewPeacock: Thanks! Here's one way to recreate that error: http://jsfiddle.net/8TjQp/ That's using the default settings of jsFiddle, all I did was fill in the HTML and JavaScript panes.

Comment: That was it. I can't believe I was such a moron.

Answer (score 1):

use hash sign (#) with ids for selector

```
$("#contains_filter_select" )
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$("#contains_filter_select" )` in order to get the `<div>` ID. It should work once you do that.

Edit: If you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/mRBJq/ it works fine.

Comment: Matches the first one. Without the hash, it creates an empty object; one that does not have the method "text". Not sure about the second one returning "null", but let's trouble-shoot one problem at a time. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When he does .text() it says that it's an object, he just isn't selecting the div.

Comment: @GregPettit & Andrew: No. Rememeber that jQuery is **set-based**. The object returned by any call to `$` with jQuery will always have a function on it called `text` (even if there are no matching elements in the set); calling it will never result in the error message shown.

Comment: I think some feedback from the person asking the question would be rather helpful here...

Comment: Yes, you're right, TJ! I'll give your answer an upvote. I do think a more detailed comment (the information in your follow-up, except right from the beginning instead of waiting for the back-and-forth: surely you know that terse answers AND comments will often be questioned) would have been more helpful, but the right answer is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors for IDs must be prefixed with "#".

`$("#contains_filter_select")` not `$("contains_filter_select")`

Comment: So the selector is valid?!?!?

Comment: Yeah, he tried a valid one in his question and showed that it returns `null`.

Comment: @Diodeus: No, but with jQuery, you always get back a jQuery instance, which always has a `text` method. The set may be empty. You'll never get an error like `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'text'` if you call `text` on the result of a `$` call in jQuery. You will in other libs.

Comment: Interesting. I've never run into that. +1 for you T.J.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included jQuery in your page, then your `$` has been overwritten with a function that gets an element by Id and has nothing to do with jQuery. Use this:

```
(function($){
    // Now $ refers to jQuery

    $("#contains_filter_select").text("abc");

})(jQuery);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7egb/)

If you have not included jQuery please see [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899107/how-to-get-jquery-div-selector-as-object/10899189#10899189).